# trivfloat + biblatex-abnt are requiring french

Tags: babel, abnt

Why is LaTeX requiring french for the following document?

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[brazil]{babel}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[style=abnt]{biblatex}
\RequirePackage{trivfloat}

\begin{document}

Nothing in french here! What's going on?

\end{document}
```

Trying to compile with:

`latexmk -pdf bug.tex`

Tail of the error log:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))

! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language 'french' yet.
(babel)                Perhaps you misspelled it or your installation
(babel)                is not complete.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Software Versions:

- Fedora release 38
- Latexmk, John Collins, 4 Apr. 2023. Version 4.80
- pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/CVE-2023-32700 patched)

Long time ago (https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6119), somebody had exactly the same issue I'm facing right now: a document loading both babel, trivfloat and biblatex (abnt style) is requiring the french language to be installed (which makes no sense to me, since there is absolutely nothing in french and I've never issued a \selectlanguage command). The solution back then was to add the french language when loading babel. Could someone explain what's going on?